# How to get integer thread id in c++11

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stdthread

c++11 has a possibility of getting current thread id, but it is not castable to integer type:

```
cout<<std::this_thread::get_id()<<endl;
```

output : 139918771783456

```
cout<<(uint64_t)std::this_thread::get_id()<<endl;
```

error: invalid cast from type ‘std::thread::id’ to type ‘uint64_t’
same for other types:
invalid cast from type ‘std::thread::id’ to type ‘uint32_t’

I really dont want to do pointer casting to get the integer thread id. Is there some reasonable way(standard because I want it to be portable) to do it?

Comment: What do you need it to be an integer for? It is guaranteed not to make sense to do arithmetic of any sort on it, and it's not meaningful outside the context of the process, so there should be no need to serialize it other than for debugging (which the `operator<<` seems to handle fine).

Comment: something like this:http://www.1024cores.net/home/lock-free-algorithms/false-sharing---false but instead of N=MAX_THREAD_COUNT I will have something like N=128 and do thread_id%N

Comment: If you really want it to be portable, then you need to be prepared for the possibility that `thread::id` isn't represented as an integer at all. The page you link to uses an array, indexed by thread ID. Have you considered using a `map<thread::id, int>` instead? Then you can use the relational operators already defined for the `id` class without doing any conversions. The standard also defines `hash<thread::id>`, so you can use the unordered containers, too.

Comment: @Rob that map would require mutexing :(

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Maybe just read write lock that lazily add to the map missing values (the next ID).

Comment: well still slow(AFAIK, could be wrong), but maybe I'm wrong. If you can produce example as an answer and prove me wrong that would be great. I mean original point is to remove hotspot, now I introduce another to get the distributed mutexes... :) Again I could be wrong

Comment: So imagine thread_id is castable, what would you do with an integer like 139918771783456? Uae it as an index in an array? Good luck with that.

Comment: If - which is probably the use case for the majority - you just want to get the thread id for dumping and logging and tracing purposes, instead of writing: ``std::to_string(std::this_thread::get_id())``, I, for one on windows find writing: ``::GetCurrentThreadId()`` much less harming to my old fingers. So if you don't care about portability, screw the standard, which tries to force you into using ugly ``iostream`` for that purpose.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAI, if you're still around: do you want the int thread ID to be unique for the life of the program?  If so, most of the answers--all the ones based on get_id()--won't work as once a thread dies the get_id() value may be reused for a new thread.

Comment: @SwissFrank or should I say CHF :P I am still around, but I think the accepted answer is ok for me, it is up to me to make sure that variable id values are unique for the duration of a program.

Comment: I haven't been referred to as CHF in 15+ years!  Anyway, my point is that if you really wanted the IDs to be unique per thread, and not just unique per currently-existing-thread, most of the answers here would have to be commented as not being solutions...

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl You can use `std::hash` on `std::thread::id` to obtain "more or less unique" value from thread id. This is not ideal, but is guaranteed to work in case thread id itself is not an integer. And it should work fine in your `id % N` case.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/74832738/119609

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The portable solution is to pass your own generated IDs into the thread.

```
int id = 0;
for(auto& work_item : all_work) {
    std::async(std::launch::async, [id,&work_item]{ work_item(id); });
    ++id;
}
```

The `std::thread::id` type is to be used for comparisons only, not for arithmetic (i.e. as it says on the can: an *identifier*). Even its text representation produced by `operator<<` is *unspecified*, so you can't rely on it being the representation of a number.

You could also use a map of `std::thread::id` values to your own id, and share this map (with proper synchronization) among the threads, instead of passing the id directly.

Comment: Aha! But there *is* a text representation! That's good enough for humans to visually find distinction between them, right?

Comment: The thread::id (or this_thread::get_id()) solution mentioned here is best, because it's not programmer-specific. See Mike's stringstream answer below to get a string or integer representation.

Comment: @Andrew I addressed that in the answer: "Even its text representation produced by operator<< is unspecified, so you can't rely on it being the representation of a number".  Seems like a shady definition of the word "best" is at hand.

Comment: "best" was not in relation to the string representation.

Comment: Also, I just did a benchmark with 10,000,000 iterations for my own sake and this_thread::get_id() is wicked fast: http://pastebin.com/eLa3rKQE Debug mode takes 0.0000002543827 seconds per call and Release takes 0.00000003652367 seconds per call for me. (Intel i5 2.60 GHz)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes The `std::async` would never return until `work_item()` finishes its work.Maybe you need a `vector` alike to store the returned value. How do you think about it?

Answer (score 126):

You just need to do

```
std::hash<std::thread::id>{}(std::this_thread::get_id())
```

to get a `size_t`.

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/id/hash):

> The template specialization of `std::hash` for the `std::thread::id` class allows users to obtain hashes of the identifiers of threads.

Comment: I think this has to be `std::hash<std::thread::id>()(std::this_thread::get_id())`, doesn't it?

Comment: Would the hash be guaranteed unique? Probably not, defeating its use as a unique thread identifier.

Comment: Michael Goldshteyn it is not, but from the comments it is clear that my usage is a bit specific...

Comment: The example as given doesn't work with at least Clang 3.4 and libstdc++ 4.8. Barry's reformulation does work, however.

Comment: thanks 888 for the answer. MS compiler does have thread::id::hash() but Barry's code is standards compliant. Hashes can collide. It's yet useful to have a hash per thread (with hopefully a collision probability near 0)

Comment: MSVC actually returns a **hashed** thread id in this case. You might as well generate your own...

Answer (score 37):

Another id (idea? ^^) would be to use stringstreams:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::this_thread::get_id();
uint64_t id = std::stoull(ss.str());
```

And use try catch if you don't want an exception in the case things go wrong...

Comment: Good answer. This would serve the purpose in general.

Comment: This is not portable, as there's no guarantee that a `std::thread::id` prints as characters that make up an integer in much the same way that it's not guaranteed that the thread id is internally represented by an integer.

Comment: @Nikos whenever an implementation chooses that an integer is insufficient. Or whenever it deems it inappropriate for any other reason. The point here is that when the specification doesn't specify it as an integer (and it doesn't, it just has some more abstract guarantees), you cannot and should not rely on it being an integer in any implementation. Simply use `std::thread::id` as type instead of some integer, that's what it exists for. And don't reinterpret its string representation as digits making up a number. Treat it as opaque or as debugging/logging output.

Comment: @blubberdiblub that's arguing out of the ivory tower of highest C++ abstraction. But as this the such born thread id is quite useless by design. All OSs I know count threads with numbers. For those the number *is* the expected value. And even every output of other OSs thread ids could always be represented as unambiguous number

Comment: @blubberdiblub On Windows `std::thread::id` is clearly defined as unsigned int.   
`using _Thrd_id_t = unsigned int;
struct _Thrd_t { // thread identifier for Win32
    void* _Hnd; // Win32 HANDLE
    _Thrd_id_t _Id;
};` So i think all OS used number to represents a thread id.

Comment: @Kenny you're kinda missing my point, though. Even if all current popular **implementations** use an integer to represent a thread ID, it's still not portable. Any C++ implementation can choose to implement the thread ID as trivially copyable type of data, not just one of the native integers. It's also not the OS that's really important here (although it could exact some influence on the implementation of the particular compiler, of course), but the specific variant of C++ compiler you're using. There's not just Visual C++ on Windows; you can have almost any other C++ compiler on Windows, too.

Answer (score 10):

One idea would be to use thread local storage to store a variable - doesn't matter what type, so long as it complies with the rules of thread local storage - then to use the address of that variable as your "thread id". Obviously any arithemetic will not be meaningful, but it will be an integral type.

For posterity:
`pthread_self()` returns a `pid_t` and is posix. This is portable for some definition of portable.

`gettid()`, almost certainly not portable, but it does return a GDB friendly value.

Comment: `pthread_self()` actually returns a `pthread_t`, which is opaque (unlike `pid_t` (returned by `gettid()`) which, while also platform-specific, is apparently an integer, at least). But +1 for the first bit, it solved my problem!

Answer (score 9):

A key reason not to use thread::get_id() is that it isn't unique for in a single program/process. This is because the id can be reused for a second thread, once the first thread finishes.

This seems like a horrible feature, but its whats in c++11.

Comment: But it could be a good thing for srand randomization seed

Comment: No. get_id() is unique within a process: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32834095/314290.

Comment: @mikhail: The answer you linked to supports this one.  It explicitly says that "terminated thread ids might be reused" which is exactly what this answer explains.

Answer (score 6):

In this way, should work:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::this_thread::get_id();
int id = std::stoi(ss.str());
```

Remember to include library sstream

Comment: Nice, but why do you assume it is an integer? It can be hex or anything else.

Comment: if you are using `std::stringstream`, then you can use its `operator >>` to convert to int. I'd actually prefer `uint64_t` as type of `id` instead of `int` if I am sure that the `id` is integral.

Answer (score 6):

Another alternative:

```
#include <atomic>

static std::atomic<unsigned long long> thread_counter;

unsigned long long thread_id() {
    thread_local unsigned long long tid = ++thread_counter;
    return tid;
}
```

The generated code for this function by g++ in x86 64-bit is just:

```
_Z9thread_idv:
        cmp     BYTE PTR fs:_ZGVZ9thread_idvE3tid@tpoff, 0
        je      .L2
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR fs:_ZZ9thread_idvE3tid@tpoff
        ret
.L2:
        mov     eax, 1
        lock xadd       QWORD PTR _ZL14thread_counter[rip], rax
        mov     BYTE PTR fs:_ZGVZ9thread_idvE3tid@tpoff, 1
        mov     QWORD PTR fs:_ZZ9thread_idvE3tid@tpoff, rax
        ret
_ZGVZ9thread_idvE3tid:
        .zero   8
_ZZ9thread_idvE3tid:
        .zero   8
```

I.e. a single branch without any synchronization that will be correctly predicted except for the first time you call the function. After that just a single memory access without synchronization.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: Not sure I understand your question... `thread_local` already describes the storage duration for `tid`. The `static` for `thread_counter` is because you don't want to expose it outside this compilation unit.

Comment: This kind of weirdly assigns thread IDs in the order you query thread ID.  (I've done something VERY similar myself, and I never liked this weirdness.)  It also assigns from zero, which isn't usual.  (For instance GDB reports thread IDs starting at 1.)

Comment: @SwissFrank: it's just a number and you shouldn't read too much in the value returned: there's no legal way to know that it was assigned when you queried it :-) . About the fact that `0` is a valid ID that is a good point and can be fixed using preincrement instead. I'll change the answer to do that.

Comment: For the right use case, e.g., a reasonably finite number of threads, a logging system, and a human using it who prefers things like '1' and '2' instead of 0x7e8000499000 or 140141742282496, this is just a ridiculously elegant solution.

Comment: I use something very similar:

`int GetThreadId() {
    static std::atomic_int threadCount{0};
    thread_local int threadId = threadCount.fetch_add(1);
    return threadId;
}`

You can init `threadCount` to any value you like (e.g. `1`).

Answer (score 5):

`thread::native_handle()` returns `thread::native_handle_type`, which is a typedef to `long unsigned int`.

If thread is default constructed, native_handle() returns 0.
If there is an OS thread attached to it, the return value is non-zero (it is pthread_t on POSIX).

Comment: Where is it specified that `std::thread::native_handle_type` is a typedef for `long unsigned`? In 30.3.1/1 we can only see `typedef implementation-defined native_handle_type; // See 30.2.3`

Comment: A dumb but simple way to discover the type is to generate a deliberate compilation error by assigning thread::native_handle() to e.g. uint8_t. Then the compiler will complain about type mismatch and will also tell you what the type is.

Comment: Well that's non-portable since it relies on particular implementation.

Comment: Well, at least if the underlying implementation uses POSIX pthread, it seems that native_handle() must be a pthread_t. Now, pthread_t is a pointer type (typedef struct pthread * pthread_t). So, it makes sense that std::thread::native_handle_type is an integer type capable of containing a pointer (e.g. size_t or unsigned long).

Answer (score 2):

it depends on what you what you want to use the thread_id for; 
you can use:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::this_thread::get_id();
uint64_t id = std::stoull(ss.str());
```

This will generate a unique id withing you process; but there's a limitation: if you launch several instances of the same process and each one of them writes their thread ids to a common file, the uniqueness of the thread_id is not guaranteed; in fact it's very likely you'll have overlaps.
In this case you can do something like:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
timespec ts;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);
uint64_t id = (ts.tv_sec % 1000000000) * 1000000000 + ts.tv_nsec;
```

now you are guaranteed unique thread ids systemwide.

Comment: The overloaded `operator<<` can print *anything*, it is wrong to assume it will always print an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this solution be helpful to someone. Call it a first time im `main()`. Warning: `names` grows indefinitely.

```
std::string currentThreadName(){
    static std::unordered_map<std::thread::id,std::string> names;
    static std::mutex mtx;

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);

    auto id = std::this_thread::get_id();

    if(names.empty()){
        names[id] = "Thread-main";
    } else if(names.find(id) == names.end()){
        std::stringstream stream;
        stream << "Thread-" << names.size();
        names[id] = stream.str();
    }

    return names[id];
}
```

Comment: do not use stringstream, it is slow, use std::to_string

Answer (score 1):

You actually can do it with casting too:

```
std::thread::id threadId = std::this_thread::get_id();    
unsigned int ThreadIdAsInt = *static_cast<unsigned int*>(static_cast<void*>(&threadId));
```

I compared **casting**, **std::hash** and **std::stringstream** on a million iterations and found that **std::hash** is the **fastest** solution with a time of **1293500ns** while **casting** is only 11ms slower with **1384200ns** and **std::stringstream** as the **slowest** at **351701200ns**.

Comment: This is just `reinterpret_cast<>`'ing the thread::id value as an unsigned int, which assumes that the underlying representation is an unsigned int (or usefully interpreted as such), but that isn't guaranteed.

Comment: The "casting" is undefined behavior; one should instead use `memcpy`.  The compiler will optimize it to the same instruction, but then it'll have the correct information in its data dependency and aliasing analysis, unlike the cast.

Answer (score 1):

`thread::id` is just a wrapper around the platform type. For all intents and purposes it's is going to be an unsigned 32-bit integer. So go ahead and treat it as an unsigned 32-bit integer.

Now, if someone is writing code for some exotic platform where this is not the case, then test for this as you move to a new platform. The answers provided thus far are so far removed from what's actually going on here that they make me wanna gouge my eyes out.

```cpp
static_assert(alignof(std::thread::id) == 4, "uh-oh!");
static_assert(sizeof(std::thread::id) == 4, "uh-oh!");

unsigned thread_id() {
  auto id = std::this_thread::get_id();
  return *(unsigned *)&id;
}
```

I get why they wanted to make it a distinct type but this is just annoying we have better things to do than to argue whether this is in line with the standard or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace std::this_thread
{
    inline _NODISCARD uint32_t get_id_2() noexcept
    {
        thread_local static const auto THIS_THREAD_ID = []()->uint32_t { std::stringstream ss; ss << std::this_thread::get_id(); return std::stoul(ss.str()); }();
        return THIS_THREAD_ID;
    }
}
```