# Using std::hash<std::thread::id>()(std::this_thread::get_id())

Tags: c++, linux, stdthread, gcc4.8, stdhash

I'm currently working on getting a C++ application to compile in both Windows and Linux, during some debugging I've found that

```
std::this_thread::get_id().hash()
```

doesn't compile on Linux with gcc 4.8 (thanks to the comments in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432100/how-to-get-integer-thread-id-in-c11/15813873#15813873?newreg=59f15841fcc2499798befaa35a1f1e60)). The suggested fix for this was to use:

```
std::hash<std::thread::id>()(std::this_thread::get_id())
```

Does anyone know if these produce the same output?

Comment: Clearly not on gcc 4.8, as one fails to compile.  ;)

Comment: How many threads in your process so you would notice difference vs binary tree? Premature optimization is root of all evil.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GCC is right to reject the code. The standard does not define a member `hash` for `std::thread::id`. C++11, 30.3.1.1:

```
namespace std {
  class thread::id {
  public:
    id() noexcept;
  };

  bool operator==(thread::id x, thread::id y) noexcept;
  bool operator!=(thread::id x, thread::id y) noexcept;
  bool operator<(thread::id x, thread::id y) noexcept;
  bool operator<=(thread::id x, thread::id y) noexcept;
  bool operator>(thread::id x, thread::id y) noexcept;
  bool operator>=(thread::id x, thread::id y) noexcept;

  template<class charT, class traits>
    basic_ostream<charT, traits>&
      operator<< (basic_ostream<charT, traits>& out, thread::id id);

  // Hash support
  template <class T> struct hash;
  template <> struct hash<thread::id>;
}
```

So using `std::hash<std::thread::id>()(std::this_thread::get_id())` is certainly a valid (actually the only valid) way of getting a hash of a thread ID.

Answer (score 0):

[`std::thread::id::hash()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/id) is not in the standard as far as I can tell.  So it is probably an extension or implementation detail.  As such, its behavior is obviously going to be implementation defined.

`std::hash<std::thread::id>()(std::this_thread::get_id())` is in the standard.

As you cannot have a thread on more than one system, nor can the `.hash()` be called in any portable code, what remains is the possibility that some platform-specific module uses `.hash()`, your generic code using `std::hash`.  You can rely on sanity and presume that `.hash()` is the same, or you can sweep your platform-specific module.  I would go with the sweep myself.