# how do you get the native handle for the currently executing thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, std, stdthread

`std::thread` has the `native_handle()` method.

how do you get the `native_handle_type` of the currently executing thread?

(no platform-specific answers, please. assume i have a library function `void foo(native_handle_type handle);` )

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16259257/4093378

Comment: what if I have a library function `void foo(native_handle_type handle)` ?

Comment: @Kerndog73, yeah i don't think that actually answers my question.

Comment: Both of those answers say it's impossible

Comment: "native" is another word for "platform specific".  What ever you are going to do with the handle (no point whatsoever in keeping that a secret) is inevitably going to be platform specific.  So the demand makes excessively little sense as posted.  Surely you can do a better job of it, start by explaining why it matters and what problem you want to solve.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74832738/119609