# C++ getting thread id. different results from std and pthread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I've seen two approaches to get the thread id which return different results.
one is used by a third party package I'm using which look like this :

```
...
#elif __APPLE__
    uint64_t tid;
    pthread_threadid_np(nullptr, &tid);
    return static_cast<size_t>(tid);
#else 
...
```

While on other places in the project I'm using the standard std way which is inheritedly cross platform

```
std::this_thread::get_id()
```

the third-party native approach return 4993544 while the std code return 0x1708b3000

Any idea how to explain the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that `std::this_thread::get_id()` is cross-platform, hence its result is NOT a real `id`, it's whatever `std` needs to find that real `id`.

It's common that by adding many layers of abstraction to a framework, accessing the real things becomes harder or even useless (as none of the framework's API accepts the Real-ID).

Where `std` is no exception, consider it yet another framework, **but** built-in of the language - hence should be used more than frameworks (unless you support some very old compilers).

Comment: is there a way to convert `std::this_thread::get_id` result to `pthread_threadid_np` result ?

Comment: @Zohar81 There is no direct conversion from `std::thread::id` to `std::thread::native_handle`, but that's a separate question - **See:** https://stackoverflow.com/q/36865846/8740349